# Test and read variables from file with JS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am creating a script which is able to read an environment file. The content can be as following:

```
var1 = 'test'
var2='test2'
var1= 'test'
var3 = 4
```

I would like to extract the key and the value, eg.:

```
var1 = 'test' -> result[0]: var1, result[1]: test
```

How can i write a function that can test if the line read with `readFile` is valid and afterwards its `key` (eg. var1) and `value` (eg. test)? Is it possible to extract both key and value with regexp without running two regexp functions?

Comment: @thefourtheye, thats a typo, it should just be a number.

Comment: @karthikmanchala, for `var1='test'` i expect an array which contains (1) the key and (2) the value. Which in this case is `var1` followed by `test`.

Comment: Its not very clear what you are trying to do? Can you please include sample inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: validation should also be done on this input? Example: if `var4 = 'test` what should be the output?

Comment: @karthikmanchala, the output should be the key and value, basically the values located on the left and right side of the equals sign, with the quotes removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your line stored, you can do something like this:

```
// line is the line you are processing, object is where you save your stuff
function processLine(line, object) {
    var parts = line.split("=");

    if (parts.length<2)
         return;

    // key is parts[0], value is parts[1]
    var key = parts.shift();
    // if we have equal signs in our value, they will be preserved
    var value = parts.join("=");

    // get rid of any trailing or preceding spaces
    key = key.trim();
    value = value.trim();

    // is the value a quoted string?
    if ((value.charAt(0)==="'" && value.charAt(value.length-1)==="'") ||
        (value.charAt(0)==='"' && value.charAt(value.length-1)==='"'))
        value = value.slice(1, value.length-1);
    // otherwise we assume it's a number
    else
        value = parseFloat(value);
    // TODO: you can check for other stuff here, such as 'true', 'false' and 'null'

    // finally, assign it to your object
    object[key] = value;
}
```

Now you just need to call your function for each line, for instance:

```
var values = {};
for (var i in lines)
    processLine(lines[i], values);
```

Caveats of this approach are numerous. They are easily fixed with some extra code, but I would recommend using something like JSON for defining your configuration values (if that is what they are). There is native support for JSON parsing in javascript, so you could just use that. Maybe you should reconsider your approach.

Comment: Makes sense :)
Another way to approach this is to use BISON grammar, there are some node modules for that and it would provide you with proper validation and a good coverage for all the kinds of situations, but I guess that needs more reading and much more work. Probably not worth it if it's your only use case and you know the possible situations very well.

Comment: One more thing you could do is merge the elements back into one string after extracting the first element, so you can have equal signs in your strings. I'll edit the answer to support this.

Comment: I won't expect any equal signs in my strings for now, only numbers and strings. The next challenge will be manipulation of the file. But i think the easiest approach is to rewrite all the vars back to the file again.

Comment: Clearly. The only issue will be remembering comments, if you had any.

Comment: Ah yes. Perhaps i should skip those as well.

Comment: You could just check if a line starts with a comment marker. I am not sure if you can have comments at the end of a line, that would make things trickier.

Comment: You could even remember comments as special "keys" in your object. Or use an array instead, as you originally intended, and just push the comments to the array as well, then write them to your file again when you export. That should work nicely and preserve comment position in your file :)

Answer (score 1):

- Read the line.. replace quotes with null

  ```
  //line = "var1 = 'test'";
  line = line.replace(/'/g, "");
  ```
- Split by delimiter `=`

  ```
  var result = line.split("="); 
  //result is an array containing "var1" and "test"
  ```

```js
line = "var1 = 'test'";
line = line.replace(/'/g, "");
var result = line.split("="); 
document.write("key => "+result[0].trim());
document.write(": value => "+result[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following JS code:

```js
function validate(str)
{
  var re = /^(\w+)\s*\=\s*(['"]?)(.*?)\2$/;
  if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
       return [m[1], m[3]];
    }
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = 
  "Result [0]: " + validate("var1 = 'test'")[0] + "<br>Result [1]: " + validate("var1 = 'test'")[1];
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```